# Read the text from a file and sort according to numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, mrjob

I have a text file, say:

```
cat 2    
dog 4  
bird 20  
animal 3
```

I want to read this file and sort like this (according to numbers):

```
cat 2  
animal 3  
dog 4              
bird 20
```

Code tried so far:

```
def txtsort(self, _, line):
words = [] 
    for word in WORD_RE.findall(line):
    words.append(word)
words_ini = words[0]
count_ini = np.array(words[1])
count_sort = np.sort(count_ini,axis = 0,kind='quikstart', order = None)
```

Comment: And what happened with that code? As posted it's broken, so if it doesn't work there should not be any surprise.

Comment: Fix your code so that `words` contains the words you want to sort.

Comment: I am trying to do this in mrjob. Is there any solution for this using mrjob

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have words in a list similar to:

```
words = [
    ('cat', 2),
    ('dog', 4),
    ('bird', 20),
    ('animal', 3)
]

result = sorted(words, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need external libraries for this. Just split each line and add it to a list, casting the second element as a number. Then sort the list by that element.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    result = [(a,int(b)) for line in f for a,b in line.split()]

result.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: I would love to hear what's wrong with this answer to make it deserve a downvote. Then I can improve it.